# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 12 in java

Tags: java, bluej

im trying to get user input a string of 12 numbers and allocate each number into the array space, though im able to allocate the numbers into the array but i got the out of bounds exception at line 12 which i dont understand why. Your help is much appreciated. :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice
{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        char [] space = new char[13];

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number ");

        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0;i<space.length;i++) 
        {
            char bCode = input.charAt(i); 
            space[i] = bCode;       //assign bCode to store in space array
            System.out.println((i+1)+"th " + space[i]);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks nambi and adam. Your solutions were correct. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are checking the `space` variable length while printing the input values

check the `input.length()` length instead of `space.length` length that's why you are getting the`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

change this

```
 here -> for (int i = 0;i<space.length;i++) 
            {
```

to this

```
for (int i = 0;i<input.length();i++) 
        {
```

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is the String `input` is not 13 characters long, meaning index 12 is out of bounds, which throws the `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Try checking the length of input before using `charAt(i)` such as

```
for (int i = 0; i < space.length; i++) {
    if (input.length() > i) {
        char bCode = input.charAt(i); 
    }
    space[i] = bCode;       //assign bCode to store in space array
    System.out.println((i+1)+"th " + space[i]);
}
```

or alternatively, you can use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char bCode = input.charAt(i); 
    space[i] = bCode;       //assign bCode to store in space array
    System.out.println((i+1)+"th " + space[i]);
}
```